# Array in C struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to have two arrays in a struct, which are initialized at start but need editing further on. I need three instances of the struct, so that I can index into a specific struct and modify as I wish. Is it possible?

This is what I thought I could do but I get errors:

```
struct potNumber{
    int array[20] = {[0 ... 19] = 10};
    char *theName[] = {"Half-and-Half", "Almond", "Rasberry", "Vanilla", …};
} aPot[3];
```

Then I access the structs as follows:

```
 printf("some statement %s", aPot[0].array[0]);
 aPot[0].theName[3];
 …
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Is that really how your `struct` is defined?

Answer (score 18):

The struct themselves do not have data. You need to create objects of the struct type and set the objects ...

```
struct potNumber {
    int array[20];
    char *theName[42];
};

/* I like to separate the type definition from the object creation */
struct potNumber aPot[3];
/* with a C99 compiler you can use 'designated initializers' */
struct potNumber bPot = {{[7] = 7, [3] = -12}, {[4] = "four", [6] = "six"}};

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  aPot[0].array[i] = i;
}
aPot[0].theName[0] = "Half-and-Half";
aPot[0].theName[1] = "Almond";
aPot[0].theName[2] = "Rasberry";
aPot[0].theName[3] = "Vanilla";
/* ... */

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  aPot[2].array[i] = 42 + i;
}
aPot[2].theName[0] = "Half-and-Half";
aPot[2].theName[1] = "Almond";
aPot[2].theName[2] = "Rasberry";
aPot[2].theName[3] = "Vanilla";
/* ... */
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can initialise structures; excuse the crappy formatting: struct potNumber aPot = { { [0]...[19] = 10 }, {"Half-and-Half","Almond","Rasberry","Vanilla".......} };

Comment: @David: yes, except for the `...`, that works. Example added in my snippet above. Thanks.

Comment: @David: Those are very GCC-style initializations (and since it's Linux, I assume GCC). I've never seen the `......` stuff though, is that even valid?

Comment: It's just the example code cut-and-pasted from the OP. TBH I did think that [0]...[19] was C99, but it's not. gcc does support [0...19] though.

Comment: Shouldn't those strings be `strcpy`d into the structs?

Comment: @MattF.: The elements of the member array `theName` are pointers. With the assignment, I'm making those pointers point to the literal strings. To use `strcpy()` I'd need to allocate memory first: `aPot[0].theName[0] = malloc(1 + strlen("hello")); /* assume it worked */ strcpy(aPot[0].theName[0], "hello"); /* use data */ free(aPot[0].theName[0]);`

Comment: That is true but (AFAIK) you will run into undefined behavior (likely a segmentation fault) when trying to mutate those strings (e.g., `aPot[0].theName[0][0] = 'h'`) due to how they're stored in the executable (most likely in rodata). Maybe define them as `const char*` (pointer to const char) if you're not going to use `strcpy`.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. `const char *` is nice to have the compiler warn about attempts to change the data, but not required.

Comment: more docs on designated initializers and their gcc extensions: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Answer (score 14):

In C struct array elements must have a fixed size, so the `char *theNames[]` is not valid. Also you can not initialize a struct that way. In C arrays are static, i.e. one cannot change their size dynamically.

A correct declaration of the struct would look like the following

```
struct potNumber{
    int array[20];
    char theName[10][20];
};
```

and you initialize it like this:

```
struct potNumber aPot[3]=
{
    /* 0 */
    { 
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 /* up to 20 integer values*/ },
        {"Half-and-Half", "Almond", "Raspberry", "Vanilla", /* up to 10 strings of max. 20 characters */ }
    },
    /* 1 */
    { 
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 /* up to 20 integer values*/ },
        {"Half-and-Half", "Almond", "Raspberry", "Vanilla", /* up to 10 strings of max. 20 characters */ }
    },
    /* 2 */
    { 
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 /* up to 20 integer values*/ },
        {"Half-and-Half", "Almond", "Raspberry", "Vanilla", /* up to 10 strings of max. 20 characters */ }
    }
};
```

But, I'm pretty sure this is not what you want. The sane way to do this required some boilerplate code:

```
struct IntArray
{
    size_t elements;
    int *data;
};

struct String
{
    size_t length;
    char *data;
};

struct StringArray
{
    size_t elements;
    struct String *data;
};
/* functions for convenient allocation, element access and copying of Arrays and Strings */

struct potNumber
{
    struct IntArray array;
    struct StringArray theNames;
};
```

Personally I strongly advise against using naked C arrays. Doing everything through helper structs and functions keeps you clear from buffer under/overruns and other trouble. Every serious C coder builds a substancial code library with stuff like this over time.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, could you give me an example of how i would enter the data, and how i would then be able to access it?

Comment: downvoted because [Flexible Array Members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) have been available since C99, 12 years before this answer was written.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: If you knew how Flexible Array Members worked, you'd not written this ill informed comment (and did downvote). FAMs only work for the very last element in a structure and come with several caveats. OP has to deal with **more than one array of varying length**. FAMs can't do that.

Comment: @datenwolf even if FAMs are not applicable here, the sentence "In C struct array elements must have a fixed size" is wrong in the presence of FAMs.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Even with FAMs only the very last element in a struct is permitted to be a FAM. Everything that's not the last element of a struct, including arrays must be fixed size.