# How to initiate and change an array as a member variable of a structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

For example,

```
struct Student
{
std::string name;
int scores[];
};
```

Is this even legal? If so, how do I put a an actual value to the array.In this program, the length of the array can be any positive integer. Would it be something like this?

```
Student s;
s.scores = int scores[length]
```

Comment: Use a vector instead.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I'm not allowed to use vectors for this program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array in C struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170525/array-in-c-struct)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this even legal?

No.

Just make things easy for yourself and use `std::vector`.

Or you can imitate `std::vector` by storing a pointer and a size as exemplified in SingerOfTheFall's answer.

If you know that `scores` will always have the same amount of elements you should use `std::array` or a raw static array, like so:

```
int scores[length]; // 'length' is a constant expression
```

Now you can't change the size of the array.

Comment: cannot use vector for this program

Answer (score 2):

Storing a pointer to the array, and the size of that array should be enough:

```
struct Student
{
    void initializeScores(int size)
    {
        scores = new int[size]{0};
        scoresSize = size;
    }

    std::string name;
    int * scores;
    int scoresSize;
};
```

Don't forget to `delete[]` the array, though. The best way is to write a proper class with a constructor and destructor; according to the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) you should also define a copy constructor and an assignment operator (and possibly a move constructor and a move assignment operator), something like:

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student(int scoresSize)
        : scoresSize(scoresSize)
        , scores(new int[scoresSize]{10})
    {
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        delete[] scores;
    }

    //copy constructor
    Student( const Student & other )
        : scoresSize(other.scoresSize)
        , scores(new int[scoresSize])
    {
        memcpy(scores, other.scores, sizeof(int) * scoresSize);
    }

    //move constructor
    Student( Student && other)
        : scoresSize(other.scoresSize)
        , scores( other.scores )
    {
        other.scores = nullptr;
    }

    //assignment operator
    Student & operator=( const Student & other )
    {
        scoresSize = other.scoresSize;
        scores = new int[scoresSize];
        memcpy(scores, other.scores, sizeof(int) * scoresSize);
        return *this;
    }

    //move assignment operator
    Student & operator=( Student && other )
    {
        scoresSize = other.scoresSize;
        delete[] scores;
        scores = other.scores;
        other.scores = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    int scoresSize;
    int * scores;
};
```

Or you can just use a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of a raw pointer to `scores`.

Comment: Don't blindly say "don't forget to `delete[]`". Explain how constructors and destructors can be used to help ensure the cleanup happens.

Comment: @NikBougalis, thanks for noting, however I can't type _that_ fast, so I added that note as a placeholder while I was editing the answer.

Comment: In this case you should follow the rule of 3 or 5. Or replace the raw pointer with a `unique_ptr` and follow the rule of 0. I think that should be mentioned when advising to use raw `new`/`delete`.

Answer (score 1):

int scores[] is a arrary with default size 0. Unfortunately, you cannot change its size, let alone adding new items. To make life easy, please use poninter to create dynamic array if necessary or just use vector instead.

Comment: No, `int scores[]` is not a pointer, it's an unsized array which is invalid in C++ as used here.

Comment: Sorry, int scores[] is something "like" constant int pointer, you  can compile it without errors but cannot assign any value to it. Please use int pointer or just vector to make life easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use array inside structure, you have to know the length and specify that

```
struct Student
{
std::string name;
int scores[3];
};

Student j = {"Jhon", {10, 11, 12}};
```

If you don't know the length you have to use `std::vector` instead of array

```
struct Student
{
std::string name;
std::vector scores;
};

Student j = {"Jhon", {10, 11, 12}};
Student s = {"Smith", {10, 11, 12,13}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use `std::vector`, I assume you also can't use things like `std::unique_ptr` which means you'll have to do a bit of memory management yourself. While this is OK, going forward, once you're not limited by homework constrains, you should greatly prefer to use the tools provided by the language to make your life easier and your program more robust.

With that out of the way, here's how you can achieve what you want:

```
struct Student
{
    Student()
        : scores(nullptr)
        , scoresSize(0)
    {
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        delete[] scores;
    }

    void initializeScores(int size)
    {
        scores = new int[size]{0};
        scoresSize = size;
    }

    std::string name;
    int* scores;
    int scoresSize;
};
```

If you know the number of scores you want when you construct the `Student` object you can do even better:

```
struct Student
{
    Student(std::string n, int size)
        : name(n)
        , scoresSize(size)
    {
        scores = new int[size]{0};
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        delete[] scores;
    }

    std::string name;
    int* scores;
    int scoresSize;
};
```

Just to nitpick, the `Student` class should follow the rule of 3 or potentially disable copy constructor and copy assignment, to avoid having memory leaks and double deletes (i.e. crashes). Also note that calling `new` in the constructor as we do here has the potential to leak memory under some circumstances which you're unlikely to ever encounter in this simplistic program. Prefer `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` to have the problem disappear automatically.