# Variable 2D array in a C struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, 2d, dynamic-arrays

This is probably a question with a simple answer but I am not finding anything similar to it with a proper solution. I am trying to create a `struct` in C that has two variables and then a two dimensional array with dimensions equal to that of the two variable parameters used to create the `struct`.

```
struct image{
  int width;
  int hight;
  int pixles[width][height];
};
```

Now I knew this wouldn't work before I even compiled it but I'm not sure how to go about making this work.

Comment: Use a pointer to a 1D array and 2-stage allocation.

Comment: THis is not possible; the size of a struct must be known at compile-time.

Comment: Reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170525/array-in-c-struct

Comment: Also see [What's the purpose of ANYSIZE_ARRAY in <winnt.h>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9195889/608639).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly as you were said in comments. There are two common idioms to *simulate* it (assuming VLA are supported):

1. you only store in the struct a pointer to a (dynamically allocated) array, then you cast it to a pointer to a 2D VLA array:

   ```
   typedef struct _Image {
       int width;
       int height;
       unsigned char * data;
   } Image;

   int main() {

       Image image = {5, 4};

       image.data = malloc(image.width * image.height);
       unsigned char (*data)[image.width] = (void *) image.data;
       // you can then use data[i][j];
   ```
2. If you dynamically allocate the structs, you can use an array of 0 size as its last element (and again cast it to a VLA pointer):

   ```
   typedef struct _Image {
       int width;
       int height;
       unsigned char  data[0];
   } Image;

   int main() {
       Image *image = malloc(sizeof(Image) + 5 * 4); // static + dynamic parts
       image->width = 5;
       image->height = 4;
       unsigned char (*data)[image->width] = (void *) &image->data;
       // you can then safely use data[i][j]
   ```

If VLA are not supported by your C implementation, you must revert to the old idiom of simulating a 2D array through a 1D pointer: `data[i + j*image.width]`